Uncertainty about the auto-correlation of a signal
I have the following signal that represent a supply voltage to an electric motor:

I compute the auto-correlation of that signal as:
   Rxy[:] = signal.correlate(
                        (X[:] - np.mean(X[:])) / np.std(X[:]),
                        (X[:] - np.mean(X[:])) / np.std(x[:]),
                    ) / len(X)

where signal.correlate is taken from the scipy package of Python.
If I plot the auto-correlation of that signal I get an almost constant plot around 1, see picture:

To me that is very strange because by looking at the signal with respect to time it does not seem so much auto-correlated. Can someone explain me what is happening?
EDIT: I tried to remove the mean and to detrend, obtaining the following:

But the situation only got marginally better:


The time plot of the signal looks highly autocorrelated. Plot X[t] vs X[t-1] to see this.
